# Jinja2 filters for dynamic registered templates

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, jinja2, django-template-filters

I've got the following code:

```
from app.utils.logic.template_filters import get_date_europe

env = Environment(
    loader=FileSystemLoader(template_dirs),
    autoescape=True,
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.i18n'],
)
env.install_null_translations()
env.filters['get_date_europe'] = get_date_europe

def render_from_text(text, **context):
    t = jinja2.Template(text)
    return t.render(**context)
```

and I want to add a custom filter to perform specific datetime formatting.
`text` is a valid template stored as string.
 The problem is that when line `{{ some_object.created_at|get_date_europe }}` is included into template, jinja throws an exception
`jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'get_date_europe'`

I set a debug breakpoint into first line of `render_from_text` and called `env.filters`, function appears to be there `'get_date_europe': <function get_date_europe at 0x10fca02f0>,`.
How can I make my filter visible to jinja?

P.S. Django 1.9 is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I tried to use `jinja2.Template(text)` which creates new instance of environment every time being called, instead of `env.from_string(text)`. This change allowed me to pass my filters to the environment before I actually load the template.
It works the following way: jinja2.Template(text) in `__new__` method runs the following code:

    `env = get_spontaneous_environment(
    block_start_string, block_end_string, variable_start_string,
    variable_end_string, comment_start_string, comment_end_string,
    line_statement_prefix, line_comment_prefix, trim_blocks,
    lstrip_blocks, newline_sequence, keep_trailing_newline,
    frozenset(extensions), optimized, undefined, finalize, 
    autoescape,
    None, 0, False, None)`

which creates new env. It's possible to pass extensions to it, but writing an extension for date formatting is far too complicated way.
So, my code now looks this way:
    
    `env = Environment(
        loader=FileSystemLoader(template_dirs),
        autoescape=True,
        extensions=['jinja2.ext.i18n'],
    )
    env.filters['format_datetime_europe'] = format_datetime_europe
    def render_from_text(text, **context):
        t = env.from_string(text)
        return t.render(**context)`